# Adding GTM tags/events on DTM event based rules

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I am using DTM for tag management and I have a requirement to add GTM tags using DTM event based rules.

I created one page load rule to load this custom code:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-XXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

and then I created an event based rule, which is a `click` event on some button, and added custom code:

```
gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'});
```

but this doesn't seems to be working exactly, I am getting either
 `gtag() is not defined` or `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

How can I make it work properly, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your page load rule that sets up the gtag code- I'm assuming that's an HTML 3rd party tag? Depending on when/how your HTML tags fire, DTM may be setting up an iframe to run it in (because you can't really append straight-up HTML to the DOM after the DOM has loaded).

You may need to switch that third party tag to javascript so it can stay on the same page and therefore have the same scope as your Event-Based Rule.

[DTM third Party](https://www.digitaldatatactics.com/index.php/2016/07/06/dtm-third-party/) has some examples of how you might do that.

Comment: Thanks Jenn, this makes sense. I try that out.